# Check if last JavaScript call is made

Tags: javascript, php, forms, xslt

I can see that all of my JavaScript is firing, except for my last push, which is going to a PHP file to generate a report (I'm using HTML/JS >> PHP >> XML + XSLT >> FOP >> PDF).

Here's my function:

```
function doReport() {

var date = $("#myDate").val().replace(/\D/g, '');

if (date.length >= 6) {
    var dateYY = date.substr(date.length - 4)
    var dateMM = date.slice(0, -4)
} else if (date.length == 5) {
    var dateYY = date.substr(date.length - 4)
    var dateMM = date.slice(0, -4)
    dateMM = '0' + dateMM;
} else {
    var dateYY = date.substr(date.length - 2)
    var dateMM = date.slice(0, -2)
    dateYY = '20' + dateYY
};
var dateDD = '01';
// var sDate = dateMM + '-01-' + dateYY;
var sDate  = new Date(dateYY, (dateMM -1 ), dateDD);
var eDate = new Date(dateYY, dateMM, 0);
var cDate = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(cDate.getFullYear(), cDate.getMonth(), 1);

if (sDate >= firstDay) {
  alert(' Please enter a month earlier than this month');
}

// alert('Month: ' + dateMM + ', Year: ' + dateYY + ', Full Date: ' + sDate + ' first day of month: ' + firstDay);
// alert('sDate: ' + sDate +' eDate: ' + eDate);
if (date == '') return alert('Missing Date - Please correct it.');

if (checkDateFld(date) === false) {
    $('#myDate').focus();
    return alert("Your starting date must be a valid date in mm-yyyy format.");
}


window.open('Apps/R_SatsEOM.php&sDate=' + sDate + '&eDate=' + eDate);
```

}

All of the validation works without a hitch, it checks to make sure that the month the report is being run for isn't in the future, but nothing happens where:

```
    window.open('Apps/R_SatsEOM.php&sDate=' + sDate + '&eDate=' + eDate);
```

should fire. How can I test this? Is there something fundamentally wrong with my JS? Or am I barking up the wrong tree, and this is a PHP issue?

Comment: One very obvious mistake is this url `Apps/R_SatsEOM.php&sDate=`: that `&` should be `?`

Comment: Could be popup blocker issues also.

Comment: No pop up blocker issues, and I fixed the`App/R_StatsEOM.php?sDate=`..., any other thoughts?

Comment: I would start by just returning the XML without all the other processing. Then return the XSL FO that is the input to FOP. If those work, I would run the XSL FO through FOP at command line to be sure there are no errors being reported by FOP and the rendering aborted.